# ClassCastException with CDI producer method and groovy class from script

Tags: groovy, jboss-weld, weld

I am learning about Groovy Language and possibilities to integrate it with CDI.

In java class path, a have a interface called `Product`. I created a CDI Producer Method that returns a `Product` type.
At another class, I performs a injection of a `Product`, that comes from the CDI Producer Method.

Out of classpath, I wrote a groovy script, with a simple groovy class, that implements the Product interface.

Inside CDI Producer Method, I use `GroovyScriptEngine` to retrieve the Class object from script, to create a CDI Bean.

I am using

- Weld version 2.2.8.Final as CDI implementation.
- Groovy at version 2.3.9.
- The Tomcat server 7.
- Using JSF 2.2.8 as well.

(thinking that problem is related only to Weld Implementation of CDI eh Groovy)

All works fine at first time. It is possible using the created bean inside JSF pages, clicking in button and performs actions at the server side, and refresh the page on browser. All declared methods and fields on groovy script class can be accessd and used with JSF pages. The CDI container performs the calling of `@PostConstruct` as well. The CDI Producer Method is can be called many time, and all works.

As said, all works fine at the first time. But when the groovy script changes, a `ClassCastException` is thrown.

Someone can help me to about this? Is this a Weld/Groovy issue, or simply not possible?

The `Product` interface:

```
package test;

/**
 *
 * @author Welyab
 */
@ProductMethodIntercetor
public interface Product {

    public void a();

    public void b();
}
```

The groovy script that implements the `Product` interface:

```
package test

class ProductImplWithGroovy  implements test.Product {
  @javax.annotation.PostConstruct
  def void init(){ 
        println "call init()"
  }

  def void a(){
      println "call a()";
  }

  def void b(){
      println "call b()";
  }

  def void c(){
      println "call c()";
  }
}
```

The producer class/method:

```
package test;

import groovy.util.GroovyScriptEngine;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.enterprise.context.spi.CreationalContext;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Any;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Default;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.AnnotatedType;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Bean;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.CDI;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.InjectionTarget;
import javax.enterprise.util.AnnotationLiteral;

/**
 *
 * @author Welyab
 */
public class ProductsTest {

    private static GroovyScriptEngine se;

    static {
        try {
            se = new GroovyScriptEngine(new URL[]{
                new File("c:/users/welyab/desktop").toURI().toURL()
            });
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Produces
    @ProductProducer
    public Product criarProduto() {
        BeanManager bm = CDI.current().getBeanManager();

        final Class klazz;
        try {
            klazz = se.loadScriptByName("script_test.groovy");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
        Class finalKlazz = klazz;

        AnnotatedType annotatedType = bm.createAnnotatedType(finalKlazz);
        InjectionTarget injectionTarget = bm.createInjectionTarget(annotatedType);

        Bean bean = new Bean() {

            @Override
            public Class getBeanClass() {
                return finalKlazz;
            }

            @Override
            public Set getInjectionPoints() {
                return injectionTarget.getInjectionPoints();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isNullable() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public Object create(CreationalContext creationalContext) {
                Object instance = injectionTarget.produce(creationalContext);
                injectionTarget.inject(instance, creationalContext);
                injectionTarget.postConstruct(instance);
                return instance;
            }

            @Override
            public void destroy(Object instance, CreationalContext creationalContext) {
                injectionTarget.preDestroy(instance);
                injectionTarget.dispose(instance);
                creationalContext.release();
            }

            @Override
            public Set<?> getTypes() {
                Set<Type> types = new HashSet<>();
                types.add(finalKlazz);
                types.add(Product.class);
                types.add(Object.class);
                return types;
            }

            @Override
            public Set getQualifiers() {
                Set<Annotation> qualifiers = new HashSet<Annotation>();
                qualifiers.add(new AnnotationLiteral<Default>() {
                });
                qualifiers.add(new AnnotationLiteral<Any>() {
                });
                return qualifiers;
            }

            @Override
            public Class getScope() {
                return ApplicationScoped.class;
            }

            @Override
            public String getName() {
                return "product";
            }

            @Override
            public Set getStereotypes() {
                return Collections.emptySet();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isAlternative() {
                return false;
            }
        };

        CreationalContext ctx = bm.createCreationalContext(bean);
        Product produto = (Product) bm.getReference(bean, finalKlazz, ctx);
        return produto;
    }
}
```

The bean to JSF page:

```
package test;

import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

/**
 *
 * @author Welyab
 */
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class TestBean {

    @Inject
    @ProductProducer
    private Product product;

    public Product getProduct() {
        return product;
    }
}
```

A simple fraggmento of JSF page that uses the bean.

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
                template="/install/ayszu-template.xhtml"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <ui:define name="body">
        <form jsf:id="form" >
            <h:commandButton value="a" action="#{testBean.product.a}" />
            <h:commandButton value="b" action="#{testBean.product.b}" />
            <h:commandButton value="c" action="#{testBean.product.c}" />
        </form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

The stacktrace with the error [all exception looks like caused by the class casting exception]

```
30-Dec-2014 18:59:37.944 WARNING [http-nio-8082-exec-24] com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute #{testBean.product.c}: java.lang.ClassCastException: test.ProductImplWithGroovy cannot be cast to test.ProductImplWithGroovy
 javax.faces.FacesException: #{testBean.product.c}: java.lang.ClassCastException: test.ProductImplWithGroovy cannot be cast to test.ProductImplWithGroovy
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
call init()
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:301)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:226)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.welyab.ayszu.core.MainFilter.doFilter(MainFilter.java:72)
    at com.welyab.ayszu.core.MainFilter.doFilter(MainFilter.java:67)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1015)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.ClassCastException: test.ProductImplWithGroovy cannot be cast to test.ProductImplWithGroovy
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: test.ProductImplWithGroovy cannot be cast to test.ProductImplWithGroovy
    at test.ProductImplWithGroovy$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.c(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:275)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 36 more

30-Dec-2014 18:59:38.182 FATAL [http-nio-8082-exec-24] com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.log JSF1073: javax.faces.FacesException obtido durante o processamento de INVOKE_APPLICATION 5: UIComponent-ClientId=, Message=#{testBean.product.c}: java.lang.ClassCastException: test.ProductImplWithGroovy cannot be cast to test.ProductImplWithGroovy
30-Dec-2014 18:59:38.191 FATAL [http-nio-8082-exec-24] com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.log #{testBean.product.c}: java.lang.ClassCastException: test.ProductImplWithGroovy cannot be cast to test.ProductImplWithGroovy
 javax.faces.FacesException: #{testBean.product.c}: java.lang.ClassCastException: test.ProductImplWithGroovy cannot be cast to test.ProductImplWithGroovy
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:89)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:301)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:226)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.welyab.ayszu.core.MainFilter.doFilter(MainFilter.java:72)
    at com.welyab.ayszu.core.MainFilter.doFilter(MainFilter.java:67)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1015)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: #{testBean.product.c}: java.lang.ClassCastException: test.ProductImplWithGroovy cannot be cast to test.ProductImplWithGroovy
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.ClassCastException: test.ProductImplWithGroovy cannot be cast to test.ProductImplWithGroovy
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: test.ProductImplWithGroovy cannot be cast to test.ProductImplWithGroovy
    at test.ProductImplWithGroovy$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.c(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:275)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 36 more
```

Comment: could you please also add the stacktrace/exception

Comment: Thank for replay. I update with the stacktrace. I notice that, if the groovy class name change, the script reload works.

Comment: This does not look like a Groovy bug to me. A reload will produce a new class. Either the proxy expects the old class and is used with the new instance, or the proxy is for the new class and used on an old instance. Looks like something in the code is caching the proxy.

Comment: @WelyabPaula do you have a requirement to use GroovyScriptEngine? Groovy's joint compilation make this code way simpler

Comment: I'd second @blackdrag's comment. Also, i believe that if you restart the application that `ClassCastException` doesn't happen, because there won't be no `ProductImplWithGroovy.class` sitting around in the classloader